# Installing git-secrets on Windows

Tags: security, github

I've been trying to get git-secrets installed for the last couple of hours, and can not seem to figure it out.  Google searching gets me almost nothing, almost all of the results are for git-secret (singular secret, not plural).

I cloned [the folder](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets#windows) to my computer and opened WindowsPower Shell in Administrator mode to run the `install.ps1` file.

This is the output that I got from PowerShell:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGFHx.png]

```
Checking to see if installation directory already exists...
Creating installation directory.
Copying files.
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\windows\system32\git-secrets' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\ricci\Downloads\git-secrets\install.ps1:15 char:1
+ Copy-Item ./git-secrets -Destination $InstallationDirectory -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\windows\system32\git-secrets:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\windows\system32\git-secrets.1' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\ricci\Downloads\git-secrets\install.ps1:16 char:1
+ Copy-Item ./git-secrets.1 -Destination $InstallationDirectory -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\windows\system32\git-secrets.1:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNo
   tFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Checking if directory already exists in Path...
Already in Path.
Adding to user session.
Done.
```

When I run `git secrets --register-aws --global` in a repo directory it returns `git: 'secrets' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`

Any idea what I need to do or where I can look for help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`install.ps1`](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets/blob/5e28df337746db4f070c84f7069d365bfd0d72a8/install.ps1) includes:

```
Param([string]$InstallationDirectory = $($Env:USERPROFILE + "\.git-secrets"))
```

It appears `$Env:USERPROFILE` is, in your session, `C:\Windows\System32`, which is not good.

Try and open a Powershell session:

- as your own Windows account (not admin)
- within your `%USERPROFILE%` Path (`C:\Users\xxx`) instead of `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: I tried this, and got the same error.  I then tried moving the git-secrets directory to `C:\Users\xxx`, and ran it again.  This got rid of the first error message, but not the second.

Comment: @CarloJ Did you operate in a Windows PowerSHell as your account? Non-Admin? What does `echo $ENV:UserProfile` return?